# Android: Can PopupMenu use different divider with Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles, android-menu

I have a PopupMenu and Dropdown Spinner.
They seem to be use the same DropDownListView style.

```
// PopupMenu
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MyActivity.this, settingsButton);

// Spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.layout_spinner, res.getStringArray(R.array.spinner_list));
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_spinner_dropdown);
mRegionSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

// style.xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">@dimen/divider_height</item>
</style>
```

But I want the PopupMenu with **white** divider, and Spinner with **black** divider.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

create a custom page like spinner if it's static data

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/violetbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="General Greeting"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

    />
<View 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:text="Birthday Greeting"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />
<View 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text3"
android:text="Anniversary Greeting"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />
<View 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:text="Christmas Greeting"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />
<View 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:text="Season's Greeting"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

otherwise do a dynamic add for the data to create same with custom spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/violetbg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="General Greeting"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnstextsize"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        />
    <View 
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Spinner has no android:divider attr.

Comment: This is NOT the answer. Have u tried?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: @EricTseng  try this                                                                    ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_chat, R.id.text_post,myarray);
spinner.setAdapter(ad);